# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

everyone!
I maintain a group of channel data in a map container, from which an individual channel data can be accessed by its channle name. With regards to this, I write a simple function `GetIRChannelData` (please see the following code). When compliing, the statement `pusIRChannelData = cit->second();` throwed an error, which read

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

All the function to do is nothing but to search for a given channel name/ID in the map container, and assign it data pointer to a temporal pointer if found. Would you please show me what's wrong?

```
const Array2D<unsigned short>* GetIRChannelData(std::string sChannelName) const
{   
    const Array2D<unsigned short>* pusIRChannelData = NULL;

    for (std::map<std::string, Array2D<unsigned short>* >::const_iterator cit =    m_usIRDataPool.begin(); cit != m_usIRDataPool.end(); ++cit) 
    {   
        std::string sKey = cit->first; 

        if (sKey == sChannelName)
        {   
           pusIRChannelData = cit->second(); // Error occurred on this line
           break;
        }
    }

    return pusIRChannelData;
}
```

Comment: Any special reason you're not using `std::map`'s `find` method instead of looping through all elements looking for the key?

Comment: As a side note, type aliases really help making code more readable: `typedef std::map<...> DataPool; for (DataPool::const_iterator ...`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear... you call a function that doesn't exist.  `map::iterator` points to a `std::pair`, which has two member objects, `first` and `second`.  Note that these are not functions.  Remove the `()` from the line in question and the error should go away.

Comment: it's a `std::map` iterator, no?  `first` is the key, which is declared as `std::string`, and `second` is the value.

Comment: @geekosaur: Yes, I misread the loop initialy, thought he was iterating over the map's value type.  Should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you, Dennis. I made such a low-grade mistake!

Comment: It's worth noting that `std::pair` only doesn't contain function pointers or functors in this particular case. Consider e.g. `std::map<std::string, void (*)()>`.

Comment: No, the error message is obscure, especially for newbies. A clear message would be something like "std::pair has no function 'second()'. Did you mean the member variable 'second'?"

Comment: Only after reading the error many times and trying to figure out where I used `term`, did I realise that it meant "THE term..." (i.e. `second`).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `cit->second` doesn't identify a function pointer.  The definition of your iterator claims it's a pointer to `(Array2D<unsigned short>)`; `pusIRChannelData` is an `(Array2D *)`, so you probably want `cit->second` instead of `cit->second()` (which tries to invoke your `(Array2D *)` as a function).